# how scroll custom listview android

Tags: android

I have a custom listview that I cant scroll it .I only can scroll it with tracball but I want to scroll it with hand.
please help me thanks
listview:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        > 
 <TextView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/setting_text_time1_alarm"
     android:gravity="right"
     /> 
 <ListView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="150dp"
     android:id="@+id/setting_listview_time"
     android:layout_margin="2dp" 
     >
 </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

items of listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/setting_text_time_list"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/setting_on_off_time"
    android:focusable="false"
/>
<ToggleButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/setting_on_off_time"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:focusable="false"
/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what device are you testing it on?

Comment: How many things are in the list? Do they go off screen? Can you provide a screen capture?

Comment: I am testing on emulator

Comment: user can add item to list .items of list can be very lots

Answer (score -1):

add a scrollview around your list like:

```
<linearlayout>
<scrollview>
<linearlayout>
<textview>
<listview>
```

....

Comment: [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) scrolls by default. Wrapping it in a `ScrollView` will only bog down the OS.

Comment: don't ever put a ListView inside a scrollView this would be extremely expensive for the System